# AssertionError: yield from wasn't used with future

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

This code:

```
import asyncio
async def wee():
    address = 'localhost'
    port = 5432
    reader, writer = asyncio.open_connection(address, port)
    message = '/t'
    print('Send: %r' % message)
    writer.write(message.encode())

async def main():
    t2 = asyncio.ensure_future(wee())
    await t2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

...produces an error AssertionError: yield from wasn't used with future
with this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ssh_as.py", line 20, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 337, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 274, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 241, in _step
    result = coro.throw(exc)
  File "ssh_as.py", line 16, in main
    await t2
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 358, in __iter__
    yield self  # This tells Task to wait for completion.
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 290, in _wakeup
    future.result()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 274, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 239, in _step
    result = coro.send(None)
  File "ssh_as.py", line 9, in wee
    reader, writer = asyncio.open_connection(address, port)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/asyncio/streams.py", line 64, in open_connection
    lambda: protocol, host, port, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 599, in create_connection
    yield from tasks.wait(fs, loop=self)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 341, in wait
    return (yield from _wait(fs, timeout, return_when, loop))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 424, in _wait
    yield from waiter
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 359, in __iter__
    assert self.done(), "yield from wasn't used with future"
AssertionError: yield from wasn't used with future
```

If I use just one variable instead of unpacking asyncio.open_connection to reader, writer and just to `dummy=asyncio.open_connection(...` there is no such error, though `dummy` object is not usable as documentation's `StreamReader` as well - `TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable`. Absolutely no idea what happens, please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the `asyncio.open_connection(address, port)` line to `await asyncio.open_connection(address, port)`. Open connection returns a future/promise etc and you need to "await" that result in order to be able to access its contents.